# Creating a calculator c++

Tags: c++

My current code is:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<cmath>
#include<cstdlib>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    char cAgain, type;
    int x, y=0;
    double addition(double num1, double num2), subtraction(double num1, double num2), division(double num1, double num2), 
        multiplication(double num1, double num2), exponential(double num1, double num2), num1, num2, total;
    do
    {
        cout << "How many operations would you like to do?" << endl;
        cin >> x;
        if (x <= 0)
        {
            cout << "Error: You must have 1 or more operations." << endl;
        }
        else
        {
            while (x != 0, x--)
            {
                y++;
                cout << "Enter in your "<<y<< " operation. (First Number (+,-,*,/,^) Second Number)" << endl;
                cin >> num1 >> type >> num2;
                switch (type)
                {
                case '+':
                    total = addition(num1, num2);
                    cout << num1 << " + " << num2 << "= " << total<< endl;
                    break;
                case'-':
                    total = subtraction(num1, num2);
                    cout << num1 << " - " << num2 << "= " << total<< endl;
                    break;
                case'/':
                    total = division(num1, num2);
                    cout << num1 << " / " << num2 << "= " << total<< endl;
                    break;
                case'*':
                    total = multiplication(num1, num2);
                    cout << num1 << " * " << num2 << "= " << total << endl;
                    break;
                case'^':
                    total = exponential(num1, num2);
                    cout << num1 << " ^ " << num2 << "= " << total << endl;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        cout << "Would you like to run the program again.(Y/N)" << endl;
            cin >> cAgain;
    } while (cAgain == 'Y' || cAgain == 'y');
return 0;
}

double addition(double num1, double num2)
{
    double total;
    total = num1 + num2;
    return (total);
}
double subtraction(double num1, double num2)
{
    double total;
    total = num1 - num2;
    return (total);
}
double division(double num1, double num2)
{
    double total;
    total = num1 / num2;
    return (total);
}
double multiplication(double num1, double num2)
{
    double total;
    total = num1 * num2;
    return (total);
}
double exponential(double num1, double num2)
{
    double total;
    total = pow(num1,num2);
    return (total);
}
```

Currently the code works as it is suppose too.
It starts by asking
How many operations would you like to do?
You enter a number say 3
Then it ask you to enter in your operation
5+5
10
Then it ask for second
10^2
100
Then it ask for third
100-10
90
Then it ask if you want to start over and run the program again.

What I am trying to change it too is  to  5+5^2-10= and it give me 20.
Essentially I want the user to be able to enter in the entire operation like 5+5^2-10= and it give me the correct answer. Allowing the user to type in a function and use '=' and return to start the calculation.

Comment: Good, but is there a specific *question* ? I read this twice and have yet to find one.

Comment: @WhozCraig What can I use to allow me to enter in a full function that uses Order of Operations like (5+5^2-10=) instead of making the user map out his equation, and enter in the previous answer and moving on.

Answer (score 2):

You can use following technique to solve an expression :

```
#include<iostream>
#include<cmath>
#include<stdio.h>
#include<cstdlib>
#include<map>
#include<stack>

using namespace std;
int expression_value(string str)
{
    map<char,int>priority;
    priority['^']=3;
    priority['*']=2,priority['/']=2;
    priority['+']=1,priority['-']=1;

    stack<char>op_stack;
    stack<int>val_stack;

    int val=0;
    for(int i=0;str[i];i++)
    {
        if(str[i]>='0'&&str[i]<='9')
          val=val*10+str[i]-'0';
        else
        {
            if(op_stack.empty()) // first operator
            {
                val_stack.push(val);
                op_stack.push(str[i]);
            }
            else if(priority[op_stack.top()] < priority[str[i]]) // current operator is more prior then previous operator. so push it to stack.
            {
                val_stack.push(val);
                op_stack.push(str[i]);
            }
            else // current operator is less prior then previous operator. so calculate previous operators resultant value
            {
                int num1,num2;
                num1=val_stack.top(); val_stack.pop();
                num2=val;
                if(op_stack.top()=='+')
                  //val_stack.push(addition(num1, num2));
                  val_stack.push(num1 + num2);
                else if(op_stack.top()=='-')
                  //val_stack.push(subtraction(num1, num2));
                  val_stack.push(num1 - num2);
                else if(op_stack.top()=='*')
                  //val_stack.push(multiplication(num1, num2));
                  val_stack.push(num1 * num2);
                else if(op_stack.top()=='/')
                  //val_stack.push(division(num1, num2));
                  val_stack.push(num1 / num2);
                else
                  //val_stack.push(exponential(num1, num2));
                  val_stack.push(pow(num1 , num2));
                op_stack.pop(); // as operator's value calculation done, pop it from the stack
                op_stack.push(str[i]); // push the new operator
            }
            val=0;
        }
    }
    val_stack.push(val); // last value

    // calculate remaining operators value
    while(!op_stack.empty())
    {
        int num1,num2;
        num2=val_stack.top(); val_stack.pop();
        num1=val_stack.top(); val_stack.pop();
        if(op_stack.top()=='+')
            //val_stack.push(addition(num1, num2));
            val_stack.push(num1 + num2);
        else if(op_stack.top()=='-')
            //val_stack.push(subtraction(num1, num2));
            val_stack.push(num1 - num2);
        else if(op_stack.top()=='*')
            //val_stack.push(multiplication(num1, num2));
            val_stack.push(num1 * num2);
        else if(op_stack.top()=='/')
            //val_stack.push(division(num1, num2));
            val_stack.push(num1 / num2);
        else
            //val_stack.push(exponential(num1, num2));
            val_stack.push(pow(num1 , num2));
        op_stack.pop();
    }
    return val_stack.top();
}
```

Here you have to pass the whole expression as string.
Operators will be stored in `op_stack` and value in `val_stack`

Comment: You really aren't helping by providing the actual code, even when the code is well written and well commented. You're spoon-feeding him an answer to a problem that isn't difficult and only requires some effort.  At best, you deprived the person of the opportunity to develop this himself and learn while doing so.

Comment: @NikBougalis No offense :) But at the beginning level everyone need some coding help... if you know what i mean. Because this code is not that easy... so may be he can do much better if he can get the basic idea about how to code using stack... thanks for ur concern... it's obviously true (y)

Answer (score 0):

You should implement a 
[binary expression tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_expression_tree)

I have just modify your program to meet your requirement:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdio>

using namespace std;

char op;

double multiplication()
{
    double product;
    cin>>product;
    while(1)
    {
        cin>>op;
        if(op == '*')
        {
            double temp;
            cin>>temp;
            product *= temp;
        }
        else if(op == '/')
        {
            double temp;
            cin>>temp;
            product /= temp;
        }
        else break;
    }
    return product;
}

double addition()
{
    double sum = multiplication();
    while(op != '=')
    {
        if(op == '+')
            sum += multiplication();
        else if(op == '-')
            sum -= multiplication();
        else
        {
            cout<<"Operator error"<<endl;
            return 0.0;
        }
    }
    return sum;
}

int main()
{
    char cAgain;
    int x;
    do
    {
        cout << "How many operations would you like to do?" << endl;
        cin >> x;
        if (x <= 0)
        {
            cout << "Error: You must have 1 or more operations." << endl;
        }
        else
        {
            while (x != 0, x--)
            {
                double result = addition();
                cout<<result<<endl;
            }
        }
    cout << "Would you like to run the program again.(Y/N)" << endl;
            cin >> cAgain;
    } while (cAgain == 'Y' || cAgain == 'y');

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Calculate some expressions like a+b,a-b,a^b,a*b etc is simple. But if you want to solve expressions like this:5+5^2-10,I think you need to learn something about [Reverse Polish notation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_Polish_notation) . It is not very difficult . Good Luck.